# Preferred way to bind methods in React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As of November 2017 I know of several ways of binding methods to React Components in order for the `this` keyword to point to the React Element that owns the method (necessary in event handlers for example)

**1. Bind in constructor**

```
class A extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this._eventHandler = this._eventHandler.bind(this)
  }

  _eventHandler() {
    // ...
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this._eventHandler} />
  }
}
```

**2. Arrow function in render()**

```
class A extends React.Component {
  _eventHandler() {
    // ...
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={()=>{this._eventHandler()}} />
  }
}
```

**3. bind in render()**

```
class A extends React.Component {
  _eventHandler() {
    // ...
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this._eventHandler.bind(this)} />
  }
}
```

**4. ES2015 arrow function in class fields**

```
class A extends React.Component {
  _eventHandler = () => {
    // ...
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this._eventHandler} />
  }
}
```

**5. @autobind decorator**

```
class A extends React.Component {
  @autobind
  _eventHandler() {
    // ...
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this._eventHandler} />
  }
}
```

**1** is the safest way because it requires no build-time transformations by babel, but it very annoying to type.

**2** and **3** have performance implications due to the binding happening on every render and the React diff algorithm

**4** and **5** requires a lot less typing than **1**, but they require support in babel and might not be part of the final specs yet. Besides that I am very against the idea of annotations (coming from a Java backend background I despise annotations because they are often overused and overly magical)

As of the latest Babel version is either **4** or **5** the recommended and safest (regarding future-compatibility) way of binding functions? Are there any other way I am not aware of? Should I keep using **1**? Also if any of these considered safe to use are there any codemods that can change my codebase to use them?

Edit: @LucaFabbri pointed to [reflective bind](https://flexport.engineering/ending-the-debate-on-inline-functions-in-react-8c03fabd144) babel transform. It looks pretty cool, but it required a non-standard babel-plugin which I don't like because it is not very future-safe. I try to avoid build-time magic as much as possible, they are fine to use if you work on only one codebase over a long period of time, but if you maintain several codebases you need to handle the build-time magic each time (plus no support in create-react-app without ejecting).

Comment: I think you have highlighted all the pros and cons of each of the methods. Having seen a lot of codebases, there is no one way that people go about this, so I expect at least 1, 2 and 3 to stick around for quite a long time. If it's future-proofing that you care about stick with 1 or 3 in my opinion.

Comment: I tried various approaches. For me, the no-brainer choice is #4 as I prefer clean code.

Comment: agree with Angelos. additionally, I don't see any reason to underscore methods since there aren't really public / private differences

Comment: I think #4 will eventually be optimized and become more prevalent. no hard data on that though, just anecdotal evidence observing the space

Comment: Take a read to https://flexport.engineering/ending-the-debate-on-inline-functions-in-react-8c03fabd144 to expand you analysis with new approaches

Comment: I've been using 1 and 3 being ignorant about arrow functions binding `this` and the `@autobind` annotation. Thank you for this question as I asked it to myself since I started learning ReactJS!

Comment: @azium It is a code convention I use, underscore methods are event handlers in my components. It is not really a public/private method thing

Comment: @dev-null yes I agree, 4 would be the best, but what is the spec state of that feature? Is it consolidated or still proposal?

Comment: @LucaFabbri looks interesting, I added it to my answer and my thoughts about it

Answer (score 3):

If binding in the constructor (method 1) is too annoying for you, I'd say the preferred method would be an arrow function on the class field (method 4), as it's a simple babel transformation, [it's a stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) (basically future-proof), and avoids the performance concerns of methods 2 and 3 (if you ever hope to take advantage of `shouldComponentUpdate` or `PureComponent`.

One method that you may not be aware of is one that I came up with (haven't seen anyone else with anything similar) specifically for avoiding methods 2 and 3 when doing `.map` over some array of data to render out a list of components that need to be passed `this.someInstanceMethod(withSomeArg)` on props. For example:

```
class CatList extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    kitties: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.instanceOf(Cat)),
  }

  adoptKitty(cat) {
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    return api.adopt(cat)
      .then(res => this.setState({ loading: false })
      .catch(err => this.setState({ loading: false, err })
  }

  render() {
    // ... other stuff ...

    {this.props.kitties.map(kitty => (
      <PureKittyCat 
        key={kitty.id} 
        // ... the problem:
        onClick={() => this.adoptKitty(kitty)}
      />
    ))}
  }
}
```

It's not immediately clear how to avoid passing a function literal on props within a `.map` like this, not only because you need to bind `this`, but you also need to pass the current element into the instance method. Most people in this situation would just give up the idea of making `PureKittyCat` a `React.PureComponent`.

My solution to this problem is to store a WeakMap on the Component instance to create a local cache (local to the parent component) that associates each `kitty` object with any methods I want to pass to the associated `PureKittyCat` component. It looks like this:

```
class CatList extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    kitties: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.instanceOf(Cat)),
  }

  this.methodCache = new WeakMap()

  adoptKitty(cat) {
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    return api.adopt(cat)
      .then(res => this.setState({ loading: false })
      .catch(err => this.setState({ loading: false, err })
  }

  render() {
    // ... other stuff...

    {this.props.kitties.map(kitty => {

      // ... the good stuff:
      if ( !this.methodCache.has(kitty) ) {
        this.methodCache.set(kitty, {
          adopt: () => this.adoptKitty(kitty),
          // any other methods you might need
        })
      }

      // as long is this is the same in-memory kitty, onClick will
      // receive the same in-memory function object every render
      return (
        <PureKittyCat 
          key={kitty.id} 
          onClick={this.methodCache.get(kitty).adopt}
        />
      )
    })}
  }
}
```

WeakMaps are the right choice for something like this to [avoid a memory-leak](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap#Why_WeakMap). And storing a new cache on the component rather than as a global cache (in its own module) avoids the possibility of running into name collisions if/when you try caching methods of the same name for the same object (here `Cat`s) across multiple components.

The only other solution to this problem I've seen is explained here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36.

Both involve some annoying setup, but that's really the only way to get achieve rendering optimizations for that scenario.

Comment: wow, this is very clever, I never had any reason to use a WeakMap before. But shouldn't you do the this.methodCache.set() call in componentWillReceiveProps or componentWillUpdate instead? Doing it in the render doesn't feel right. Just want to add that arrow functions in render are not bad (the performance hit is negligible, I remember reading a tweet from Dan Abramov where the tested this), what is bad is arrow functions as props. So doing an `Array.map(() => {})` is okay but `<Component onClick={()=>{...} />` is not

Comment: @Hoffmann , thanks for the reply! Doing it in `.render` is indeed the right place to call `this.methodCache.set(obj, {})` because the crucial piece is the `obj` you pass in to uniquely associate with some methods, and those `obj`s aren't available in `componentWillReceiveProps` or `componentWillUpdate`. And I think you've got some facts mixed up about arrow functions in `.render` vs. arrow functions on `props`. I'll point you [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) and [here](https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578) for some clarification.